# 'filename-1.pdf' not found Asymptote

Tags: errors, texmaker, asymptote

I am trying to run Asymptote code embedded in a tex file. The pdf generated has no asymptote figure but other latex stuff appear.  I get a warning that file "filename-1.pdf" not found. I am using Texmaker 5.0.4 with MikTex 2.9. I ran the command PdfLatex+Asymptote+PdfLatex.

Edit:
Since a code snippet was asked, I ran this file that Akira Kakuto suggested as filename.tex and I am still getting an error,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{asymptote}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\begin{asy}
size(200);
pen[] p={red,green,blue,magenta};
path g=(0,0){dir(45)}..(1,0)..(1,1)..(0,1)..cycle;
tensorshade(g,p);
dot(g);
\end{asy}
\immediate\write18{asy \jobname*.asy}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: would you mind posting what did you try? It is difficult for people to help if they don't know what you tried.

Comment: @bingung I have now added a code snippet

Comment: Run `pdflatex --shell-escape` twice on the input. You may need to edit your editor preferences to add `--shell-escape`, or run the command in a terminal window.

Comment: @AlexG I did run it that way but it seems to be still giving the same error. The editor preference now looks like this-https://imgur.com/a/68dCKuj

Comment: Editors sometimes break things. Did you try running `pdflatex` in a terminal (command line window)? (Works for me.)

Comment: If your distribution comes with `rubber` just run it on your file; TeXmaker lets you choose a User defined quickbuild command (Configure -> QuickBuild -> User); `rubber` automates all the process; I understand that `latexmk` does also, but I haven't used it.

Comment: Same way for me! Have you some issues?

Comment: *@cookiemonster when you open filename-1.asy, is the line defaultfilename="filename-1"; there? if you just compile filename-1.asy with Asymptote, is the pdf file produced? – bingung May 11 at 14:05* To answer this question : "No". There is only an error : pic.addBox(position,position,min(f),max(f)); ^C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX/asymptote/plain_Label.asy: 321.15: runtime: It is the same error as on the subject : [Asymptote in MiKTeX is broken(?)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/573291/asymptote-in-miktex-is-broken) from the 2 décember. Thank you,

Comment: When I remove `\immediate\write18{asy \jobname*.asy}` from your code, and run with F1 on TexMaker (Asymptote Chain), it works well. Moreover, make sure your MikTeX and Asymptote software (not package) to be updated.

Answer (score 0):

I'll show an example by using a sample in the version 2.65:

```
% filename.tex
% Compile twice as:
% pdflatex -shell-escape filename.tex
% pdflatex -shell-escape filename.tex
%
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{asymptote}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\begin{asy}
size(200);
pen[] p={red,green,blue,magenta};
path g=(0,0){dir(45)}..(1,0)..(1,1)..(0,1)..cycle;
tensorshade(g,p);
dot(g);
\end{asy}
\immediate\write18{asy \jobname*.asy}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It seems I am still getting the same error. Just to clarify in the "For .asy files" section in Texmaker in "Quick build" it reads as "C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/miktex/bin/x64/asy.exe" -f pdf -noView %.asy|"C:/Program Files/Adobe/Reader 11.0/Reader/AcroRd32.exe" %.pdf. Is this correct?

Comment: Sorry, I don't use TeXmaker, and I don't know it.
I only showed how to compile in command prompt.

Comment: @cookiemonster The setting in 'Quick Build' ---> 'For .asy files' is not relevant if you run a file with `.tex` extension; it is only relevant when you run files with `.asy` extension. When you run `filename.tex`, is a file called `filename-1.asy` produced? (using `pdflatex` only)

Comment: @bingung Yes, using ````pdflatex````, ````filename-1.asy```` is being produced.

Comment: @cookiemonster when you open `filename-1.asy`, is the line `defaultfilename="filename-1";` there? if you just compile `filename-1.asy` with `Asymptote`, is the pdf file produced?