# asymptote incompatible version warning after upgrading to texlive 2021

Tags: texlive, asymptote

After upgrading to texlive 2021 I have noticed that the version of the asymptote binary file is 2.69 and not 2.70. When I use asymptote I get a warning

> Welcome to Asymptote version 2.69 (to view the manual, type help)
> warning [version]: using possibly incompatible version 2.70 of plain.asy

Does someone else experiment the same behaviour?

Comment: Do you have a second version of asy that is getting picked up? What does `which asy` return?

Comment: @HerbSchulz `/home/hafid/texlive/2021/bin/x86_64-linux/asy`

Comment: and if you type `asy -version`  on the commandline what does it report?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle `Asymptote version 2.69 [(C) 2004 Andy Hammerlindl, John C. Bowman, Tom Prince]

ENABLED OPTIONS:
WebGL    3D HTML rendering
OpenGL   3D OpenGL rendering
XDR      external data representation (portable binary file format)
GC       Boehm garbage collector

DISABLED OPTIONS:
GSL      GNU Scientific Library (special functions)
FFTW3    Fast Fourier transforms
CURL     URL support
Readline interactive history and editing
Editline interactive editing (if Readline is unavailable)
Sigsegv  distinguish stack overflows from segmentation faults
`

Comment: in cygwin tl2021 I get 2.70, I just tried on a linux box where I have tl2021 and it didn't run at all due to missing libglut library which I don't want to fix now.  someone with a linux tl2021 should be able to confirm what they get.

Comment: With TeX Live 2021 on Linux I can reproduce the issue (Asymptote 2.69 binary with 2.70 support files).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the issue was due to mismatched binaries/support files in TL 2021 and was resolved by TL's maintainers.

Comment: Crosslink for possible future readers, [Asymptote in MiKTeX is broken(?) - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/573291/asymptote-in-miktex-is-broken) looks somewhat related.

Answer (score 0):

Just track down and delete all versions of Asymptote from your system and reinstall 2.70.

Comment: Since the OP mentions installing using TeX Live which still ships 2.69 binaries, reinstalling it in the same way would not solve the issue.

Comment: I meant to install asy from the offical site: https://asymptote.sourceforge.io/

Comment: Instead, if you want to use the TeXLive 2021 version and if there really is a problem with the MSWindows binaries in that distribution, you can obtain the correct 2.70 versions that I submitted: http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/asymptote/binaries/x86_64-windows/texlive/asy.exe or http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/asymptote/binaries/i386-windows/texlive/asy.exe

Comment: I relayed this report to the TeXLive 2021 developers and I believe they are going to update the binaries for several platforms. It is essential that the binary and base files have matching versions.

Comment: Any hints on how to track down all versions of Asymptote? Right now this represents an annoyingly complex [user journey](https://www.appcues.com/blog/user-journey-map) that may well cause people to turn to other tools. Personally I'd have to think a bit even to track down all the versions of TeXLive I have installed.

Comment: On a UNIX system, you can do something like this: locate x86_64-linux/asy