Texstudio dont show Asymptote figure
I am trying to display the following Asymptote figure:
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[inline]{asymptote}
\begin{document}
\begin{asy}
size(7cm,0);
pair A, B, C, D;
A=(0,0);
B=(2,1);
C=(2,2);
D=(4,0);
draw(A--B,red);
draw(C--D,blue);
\end{asy}
\end{document}

When I compile with texstudio, the pdf file is not displayed. I go back to the source file and when I compile the file ....-1 generated by texstudio I get an error. I configured texstudio (asymptote and Ghostscript) but the problem is still there.
log:
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.26 (MiKTeX 24.4) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2024.12.30)  30 DEC 2024 14:47
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**./figasy-1.tex
(figasy-1.tex
LaTeX2e <2024-06-01> patch level 2
L3 programming layer <2024-05-27>
! Undefined control sequence.
l.9 \includegraphics
                    {\ASYprefix\jobname-1_0}%
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
l.9 \includegraphics{\ASYprefix
                               \jobname-1_0}%
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.


! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.9 \includegraphics{\ASYprefix\jobname
                                       -1_0}%
You're in trouble here.  Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.

Missing character: There is no f in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no i in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no g in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no a in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no s in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no y in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no - in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no 1 in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no - in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no 1 in font nullfont!
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.9 \includegraphics{\ASYprefix\jobname-1_
                                          0}%
I've inserted a begin-math/end-math symbol since I think
you left one out. Proceed, with fingers crossed.

LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <7> on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <5> on input line 9.
! Extra }, or forgotten $.
l.9 \includegraphics{\ASYprefix\jobname-1_0}
                                            %
I've deleted a group-closing symbol because it seems to be
spurious, as in `$x}$'. But perhaps the } is legitimate and
you forgot something else, as in `\hbox{$x}'. In such cases
the way to recover is to insert both the forgotten and the
deleted material, e.g., by typing `I$}'.

! Extra }, or forgotten $.
l.10 }
      %
I've deleted a group-closing symbol because it seems to be
spurious, as in `$x}$'. But perhaps the } is legitimate and
you forgot something else, as in `\hbox{$x}'. In such cases
the way to recover is to insert both the forgotten and the
deleted material, e.g., by typing `I$}'.

)
! Emergency stop.
<*> ./figasy-1.tex
                  
*** (job aborted, no legal \end found)

 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 22 strings out of 473865
 443 string characters out of 5735021
 1925908 words of memory out of 5000000
 23008 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 558069 words of font info for 36 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 18i,1n,18p,91b,63s stack positions out of 10000i,1000n,20000p,200000b,200000s
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!


What distribution are you using?

I use Texstudio

texstudio is an editor. I mean like miktex, texlive,... mactex

Sorry. I use Miktex

I would suggest using texlive for asymptote. Miktex uses a ghostscript file with naming conflicts to other ghostscript files (at least for me). Once you have texlive, run the file as follows: lualatex file.tex asy file-1.asy lualatex file.tex

Thanks for your reply. I will try Texlive.

And for Miktex, is there no solution?

It depends on the problem. For the naming conflict I experience on my machine, you have to rename the ghostscript executable every time you update miktex - hence my switch to texlive

I installed Texlive and restarted my PC. I have the same problem.

Hmm, could you post the .log file to the question, along with the commands you run?

"I get an error" doesn't allow anyone to help. What error did you get?

David Carlisle when I compile with texstudio (Miktex), the pdf file is not displayed. The same problem with Texlive.

Is it necessary to configure Texstudio to work with Texlive after installing Texlive. In my pc I have both Texstudio and Texlive installed.

I found the solution by following this answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/700578/asymptote-code-generates-asy-files-but-asymptote-execution-fails?rq=1

That is the naming conflict I mentioned. I'm glad you were able to get it sorted out.

I found the solution by following this answer:

https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/700578/asymptote-code-generates-asy-files-but-asymptote-execution-fails?rq=1
